# Vue2.7 vue-cli-service cannot start normally

Tags: node.js, vuejs2

A type error occurred while running the `serve` command.

```bash
$ vue-cli-service serve
 INFO  Starting development server...
 ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')
    at toIdentifier (/Users/minskiter/Desktop/Code/QWikiFE/node_modules/serve-index/node_modules/http-errors/index.js:257:14)
    at forEachCode (/Users/minskiter/Desktop/Code/QWikiFE/node_modules/serve-index/node_modules/http-errors/index.js:228:16)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at populateConstructorExports (/Users/minskiter/Desktop/Code/QWikiFE/node_modules/serve-index/node_modules/http-errors/index.js:226:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/minskiter/Desktop/Code/QWikiFE/node_modules/serve-index/node_modules/http-errors/index.js:29:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1191:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1245:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1069:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:904:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1093:19)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a special case. Problem solved when I deleted `yarn.lock` and re-executed `yarn` command.